# Create VIEW that summarizes 4 tuples in one

Tags: mysql, database, view, pivot, mariadb

I want to create a SQL VIEW that reformates my Data

That is the tabel I created. As ports need to be Unique I put them in one Column:

```
MariaDB [admindb]> select * from table_tennant;
+-------+----------+--------------+----------------+
| port  | protocol | tennant_name | tennant_domain |
+-------+----------+--------------+----------------+
| 10000 | https    | test         | test.test.de   |
| 10001 | smtp     | test         | test.test.de   |
| 10002 | mgmt     | test         | test.test.de   |
| 10003 | solr     | test         | test.test.de   |
| 10010 | https    | test2        | test2.test.de  |
| 10011 | smtp     | test2        | test2.test.de  |
| 10012 | mgmt     | test2        | test2.test.de  |
| 10013 | solr     | test2        | test2.test.de  |
+-------+----------+--------------+----------------+
```

The 4 rows for each tennant shall be displayed as one, like this

```
+----------------+--------------+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| tennant_domain | tennant_name | https_port | smtp_port | mgmt_port | solr_port |
+----------------+--------------+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| test.test.de   | test         |      10000 |     10001 |     10002 |     10003 |
+----------------+--------------+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

that is only working for one of tennant in the table. If I put in a second one my SELECT statements for the VIEW return more than one Result which leads to an error.

```
MariaDB [admindb]> select * from view_ausgabe;
ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row"
```

Here's my VIEW definition

```
MariaDB [admindb]> CREATE VIEW view_ausgabe AS SELECT tennant_domain, tennant_name,
    -> (SELECT port from table_tennant WHERE protocol = 'https' GROUP BY tennant_name AND tennant_domain) AS https_port,
    -> (SELECT port from table_tennant WHERE protocol = 'smtp' GROUP BY tennant_name AND tennant_domain) AS smtp_port,
    -> (SELECT port from table_tennant WHERE protocol = 'mgmt' GROUP BY tennant_name AND tennant_domain) AS mgmt_port,
    -> (SELECT port from table_tennant WHERE protocol = 'solr' GROUP BY tennant_name AND tennant_domain) AS solr_port
    -> FROM table_tennant GROUP BY tennant_name;
```

How can I create a new Row in the VIEW for each tennant?

Thanks for your help.
André

Comment: The technique is called "pivoting".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
create view view_ausgabe as
select 
    tennant_domain,
    tennant_name,
    max(case when protocal = 'https' then port end) https_port,
    max(case when protocal = 'smtp'  then port end) smtp_port,
    max(case when protocal = 'mngt'  then port end) mngt_port,
    max(case when protocal = 'solr'  then port end) solr_port   
from mytable
group by tennant_domain, tennant_name
```